# List in Sharepoint Preview Pane View, how do i get the item to be filled with the 1st item by default?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

The Sharepoint Preview pane works ok, and will fill the information in when I hover over the first item on the left.

But I want the first item information to be filled in when I load the page, can this be done when in Preview Pane View?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but if by "filled in" you actually mean having the 1st item automatically previewed as you enter the page you would maybe at:

- use some JavaScript in a CEWP and load some jQuery library (just for the sake of easiness of coding later)
- use proper selectors to call the functions equivalent (onmouseover)

[image]